# error message using .insert on a string

Tags: java, string, insert

here's the code 
                                 `DNA_seq1.insert(0,j.charAt(x));
             DNA_seq2.insert(0,k.charAt(e));
             DNA_align.insert(0,"|");`
where DNA_seq1, DNA_seq2, and DNA_align are strings, as are j and k

and here's the error:

```
DNA.java:151: error: array required, but String found
                             DNA_seq1.insert(0,j[x]);
tion [x][e]take the element from the DNA sequence and ins
f the array we are building
                                                    ^
DNA.java:152: error: array required, but String found
                                 DNA_seq2.insert(0,k[e]);
                                                    ^
DNA.java:153: error: cannot find symbol
                                 DNA_align.insert(0,"|");
                                          ^
  symbol:   method insert(int,String)
  location: variable DNA_align of type String
```

i seriously don't understand why im getting this error. im thinking its something obvious but my mind is kind of burnt at this point, and its just not clicking.

Comment: The source code in the error message display does not match the source code at the top of your post.

Comment: The error message doesn't match your code. Also I think you are mixing up data types.

Comment: i apologize i copied the error messsage from the wrong part of the cmd  window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell from your post what's going on.  But ...

```
DNA_align.insert(0,"|");
```

If `DNA_align` really is a `String`, then there's no `insert` method, as AnubianNoob pointed out.  If you're trying to insert `|` before the first character of the string, then you can just concatenate it, like this:

```
"|" + DNA_align;
```

Also, note that strings are *immutable* in Java; if `s` is a `String`, there is **no** method `s.method(whatever)` that modifies the contents of `s`.  There are some methods that make changes to the string and return the changed string as a *new* string, but `s`'s contents will not be modified.  So if you were hoping for a method that changed `DNA_align` by inserting something into it, forget it.  You have to reassign `DNA_align`, like:

```
DNA_align = "|" + DNA_align;
```

Answer (score 0):

String doesn't have an `insert()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Anubian Noob is correct, there is no insert() function. If you want to do this you can do something like:

```
String str = "Hello ";
str = str.substring(0, 5) + "World" + str.substring(5, str.length());
```